# return day of week when timestamp passed into date function php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to return the day of the week based on the date that i pass into the date() function but it's not working. I have this:

```
echo date('N');
echo date('N', '2011-05-11');
```

Today is thursday, so these both return 4 no matter what I pass into it for a date. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('N', strtotime('2011-05-11'));
```

date expects a timestamp as a second parameter, thats why you need to convert your string to a valid timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use "D" instead of "N".  N returns the index of the day and D returns the name.

Comment: He is asking for a numeric representation of the day of week.